# How to add formatted paragraph (fpar) to Power Point presentation, right aligned, inside a place holder

Tags: r, powerpoint, officer

I have the following code in R, using the library officeR, to create power point presentations.

No matter how I set the property "text.align" of the fp_par object (of fpar), the title remains centered.

Is there a way to add the new paragraph of text, right aligned, in a place holder added with the function add_ph_empty_at()?

Thank you!

```
require(magrittr)
require(officer)

def_text <- fp_text(color = "black", italic = FALSE, font.size = 20)

lastPhId <- function(presentation) {
  index = presentation$cursor
  x <- slide_summary(presentation, index = index)
  x <- x[x$type == "body", ]
  max(as.numeric(x$id))
}

TITLE = fpar(ftext("My Title", prop = def_text))
TITLE <- update(TITLE, fp_p = fp_par(text.align = "left"))

doc <- read_pptx()
doc %<>% add_slide(layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme") 
doc %<>% ph_empty_at(left = 3, top = 3, height = 1, width = 4, bg = "yellow") 
doc %<>% ph_add_fpar(value = TITLE, id_chr = lastPhId(doc))

print(doc, target = "ph_add_fpar.pptx")
system("cmd.exe", input = "ph_add_fpar.pptx")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just updated `officer` on Github, it's now solved. You will need to use new argument `par_default` that says (if FALSE): *don't use the placeholder default paragraph properties but use the one of the `fpar`object*.

```
require(magrittr)
require(officer)

def_text <- fp_text(color = "black", italic = FALSE, font.size = 20)

lastPhId <- function(presentation) {
  index = presentation$cursor
  x <- slide_summary(presentation, index = index)
  x <- x[x$type == "body", ]
  max(as.numeric(x$id))
}

TITLE = fpar(ftext("My Title", prop = def_text))
TITLE <- update(TITLE, fp_p = fp_par(text.align = "left"))

doc <- read_pptx()
doc %<>% add_slide(layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme") 
doc %<>% ph_empty_at(left = 3, top = 3, height = 1, width = 4, bg = "yellow") 
doc %<>% ph_add_fpar(value = TITLE, id_chr = lastPhId(doc), par_default = FALSE)

print(doc, target = "ph_add_fpar.pptx") %>% browseURL()
```